# Unicode in storedProcedure parameters

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedures, unicode, parameters, parameter-passing

I have table called City with this schema :

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[City](
    [Id] [bigint] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [Name] [nvarchar](50) NOT NULL,
    [CreatedDate] [datetime] NOT NULL,
    [CreatedBy] [nvarchar](256) NULL,
    [UpdatedDate] [datetime] NOT NULL,
    [UpdatedBy] [nvarchar](256) NULL,
    [SoftDelete] [bit] NOT NULL,
    [LanguageKey] [nvarchar](2) NOT NULL DEFAULT (''),
    [ProvinceName] [nvarchar](50) NULL DEFAULT (''),
    [CityImageId] [bigint] NULL,
    [CityDescription] [nvarchar](500) NOT NULL DEFAULT (''),
    [CityLinkTo] [nvarchar](100) NOT NULL DEFAULT (''),
    [CityCode] [nvarchar](100) NOT NULL DEFAULT (''),
 CONSTRAINT [PK_dbo.City] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
    [Id] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY]

GO

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[City]  WITH CHECK ADD  CONSTRAINT [FK_dbo.City_dbo.Image_CityImageId] FOREIGN KEY([CityImageId])
REFERENCES [dbo].[Image] ([Id])
GO

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[City] CHECK CONSTRAINT [FK_dbo.City_dbo.Image_CityImageId]
GO
```

And there is a stored procedure with this code :

```
ALTER Proc [dbo].[InventoryReport]  
(
 @startDate datetime , 
 @endDate datetime ,
 @cityName nvarchar(50)
)
AS
Begin 

Select Id , Name , AllPlace , InventoryPlace , case when Percentage is null then Convert(nvarchar(5),0) else Convert(nvarchar(5) ,Percentage )End AS Percentage
    From (
            Select c.id , c.Name  Name, count(p.id) AllPlace , count(inventoryPlace.InventoryId) InventoryPlace ,
                        ROUND( Convert(float , NULLIF(count(inventoryPlace.InventoryId), 0)  )/ Convert(float,NULLIF(count(p.id), 0)  ),2,null) Percentage
                        from Place  p
                    left join (
                            Select id InventoryId , name  from (
                            Select ROW_NUMBER() Over(Partition by  id , name  Order by  id , date) rn,
                                    * from (
                                    Select  
                                             p.id , p.name , i.date
                                             from Place  p  
                                                left join Room r    on  p.id = r.placeid            and p.SoftDelete = 0    and r.SoftDelete = 0 
                                                join RoomService rs on  r.id = rs.roomid            and rs.SoftDelete = 0 
                                                join inventory  i   on  rs.id = i.roomServiceId     and i.SoftDelete = 0    
                                                                        AND i.date >= @startDate  and i.date <@endDate  and Price <>0 
                                    Group By  p.id , p.name , i.Date 
                                    )a 
                            )r 
                            where r.rn =  DATEDIFF(day , @startDate , @endDate) 
                        )inventoryPlace
                            on p.Id = inventoryPlace.InventoryId
                        right join City c           
                            on  c.id = p.CityId and c.SoftDelete = 0 
                        Where 
                            (@cityName is null OR @cityName = N'' OR c.Name = @cityName) and  p.SoftDelete = 0   and IsVisible = 1
                        Group By c.id , c.name

            ) As PlaceInventoryReport
Order by Id
END
```

the Name field in City Table is `Nvarchar(50)` and `@cityName` is `nvarchar(50)` either. I execute these below codes :

```
exec InventoryReport @startDate='2016-07-22 00:00:00',@endDate='2016-08-21 00:00:00',@cityName =N'بیرجند'


exec InventoryReport @startDate='2016-07-22 00:00:00',@endDate='2016-08-21 00:00:00',@cityName ='بیرجند'
```

the first execute generate by Sql Profiler and call from application,then results nothing (that is wrong ) and the second one call handy by myself and results one record. the difference is `N'`

the both values 'بیرجند' are the same in character and I've copied them from place.
I can't realize what's wrong and why do these two execute statement result differently?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: N-prefix tells sql server to treat the string as a unicode value.whereas if don'y mention the same it will be look up as an string..more info here :  https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/239530

Comment: @Malcolm When we define datatype of column to NVARCHAR it store the value in UNICODE format or just a string? If it stores as string then why we shouldn't use varchar of 8000 char lenth? If it stores in UICODE format the why the value didn't match?

Comment: @samira Did you used accurate collation for the Language to the column..?

Comment: @RajeshRanjan Yes i used colation but it dosent work either.

Comment: @samira Can you please share table script and some sample record..?

Comment: @samirariazati Kindly verify if you inserting value without UNICODE identification (N'') to the column..

Comment: What does return `select name * from city order by name` - you may have duplicate cities?

Comment: @Arvo, I'm really thanks i had duplicate cities. it's solved.

Answer (score 3):

It's declaring the string as **nvarchar** data type, rather than **varchar**

1. You may have seen Transact-SQL code that passes strings around using
   an N prefix. This denotes that the subsequent string is in Unicode
   (the N actually stands for National language character set). Which
   means that you are passing an NCHAR, NVARCHAR or NTEXT value, as
   opposed to CHAR, VARCHAR or TEXT.

   To quote from [Microsoft](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-IN/library/ms186939.aspx):
2. Prefix Unicode character string constants with the letter N. Without
   the N prefix, the string is converted to the default code page of
   the database. This default code page may not recognize certain
   characters.

Comment: thanks , but  as I wrote, i have declared the column and the parameter as Nvarchar(50).

Comment: @samirariazati Yes, you have declared the param as `NVARCHAR(50)`, but you're assigning a non-unicode value to it. And that won't work. To make it work, everything should be in unicode.

Comment: But I try with the same code you mention I got result correct, but in your case may your table schema issue , can you please share your table script .

Comment: @NazirUllah I've edited the question and added the schema.

Comment: your script and sp is seen to correct check may you are trying with duplicate or other table data